# what is difference between single line and multiple line comments in java?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I just want to know that what is the difference in single in multiple line comments in java programming language.

multiple line comments

```
/*
 * This is line 1
 * This is line 2
/*
```

single line comment

```
// This is line 1
// This is line 2
```

Then what would be the difference in these two comments in terms of program translation from **.java** to **.class** (or in other words why do we need single line comments, when already we have multiple line comments).
I already know that comments are removed by compilers in **Lexical Analyzer** phase.

Comment: Because `//I'm a single comment` is easier than `/* I'm a single comment */`.

Comment: One is multiple lines, one is single lines.

Comment: "Then what would be the difference in these two comments in terms of program efficiency (or in other words why do we need single line comments, when already we have multiple line comments). I already know that comments are removed by compilers in Lexical Analyzer phase." - These two statements conflict.  There's no efficiency difference.  It doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a convenience for the programmer. I do not, for instance, want to prefix each line with a `//` when I'm writing a paragraph of comments. Also, `/* */` allows you to put comments 'inline',

```
System.out.println(2 + /* inline comment */ 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

No difference to the compiler just to the programmer.

I use `/**/` if i have to write longer comments.

`//` is great to comment out lines of code when debugging especially when you have several lines of code and you want to uncomment a single line in the middle

```
// statement 1
// statement 2
statement 3
// statement 4
```

is easier to achieve than

```
/* statement 1
   statement 2
*/
statement 3
/*
   statement 4
*/
```

But in the end it's all about personal taste.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. It comes down to user preference.

However, special variations on those syntaxes are interpreted by [Javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) for generating documentation.

```
/**
 * Short one line description.
 *
 * Longer description. If there were any, it would be
 * here.
 * <p>
 * And even more explanations to follow in consecutive
 * paragraphs separated by HTML paragraph breaks.
 *
 * @param  variable Description text text text.
 * @return Description text text text.
 * @throws IOException Explanation of why this exception is thrown.
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference whatsoever. All comments are removed so at execution comments don't impact the program, regardless of their format. It's a matter of convenience.

Answer (score -1):

It is my suggestion

**single**

single line comment for describes the class, interface, method or variable.

**multiple**

Only use multi-line comments to comment out sections of code